# Unit Testing - XUnit - IAssemblyFixture -The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

Right now, i would like to share the context entire assembly. To sort out this use-cases, i have started using IAssemblyFixture : this is how my code looks

```
-- Context
public class AssemblyLevelRepoFixture
    {
}


    public class TestBaseAssemblyFixture : Xunit.Extensions.AssemblyFixture.IAssemblyFixture<AssemblyLevelRepoFixture>
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper;
        private readonly AssemblyLevelRepoFixture fixture;
    }

    public class SampleTest : TestBaseAssemblyFixture
    {
        
        public SampleTest(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, AssemblyLevelRepoFixture fixture) : base (testOutputHelper, fixture)
        {
            // hellow how are you;
        }

        
        public void FirstTest()
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
```

-- I am facing issue : The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: AssemblyLevelRepoFixture fixture

Comment: `AssemblyLevelRepositoryFixture` and `AssemblyLevelRepoFixture` are different classes, I guess

Comment: This was a mistake while copying code and modifying - I don't have two classes. assume one class is being used in all the places.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this attribute:

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Extensions.AssemblyFixture;

[assembly: TestFramework(AssemblyFixtureFramework.TypeName, AssemblyFixtureFramework.AssemblyName)]
```